# Is there a way to script to mark Mails as read directly from the notification popup

Tags: applescript, mail.app, email

I get a lot of emails in a day, most of them I don't even need to read. I will the info I need just from the notification.

Is there a way to script the clicking of "mark as read" from the notification pop up? That way I can then assign that script to a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: You can always make a rule that marks certain (or all) mails as read.

Comment: I find doing cmnd+a then clicking mark as read works, or selecting the ones while holding cmnd...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about a shell script per se, but you could try scripting something in Automator that could run based upon an input of finding all mail messages marked as unread and then take an action on them. You may have to play around with it a bit, but it should be a solid solution.